# Scripting engine embeddable in C++ that can be terminated at will?

Tags: library, c++, api, programming, scripting

I'm making a programming game in C++ and Qt, but have a unique constraint as far as my choice in engines go; because it's possible that the player may write code that loops infinitely or takes a long time to run, *I need to be able to terminate a scripting engine's execution at any time.*  [I asked a question about this on StackOverflow yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386170/how-to-reliably-kill-a-thread-in-qt-c), and unfortunately there's no way to kill a thread in C++ without potentially causing resource problems (locks not being released, memory leaks, etc.).

I was advised that I need a scripting engine that allows me to terminate scripts at will without jeopardizing the player's session.  **What options do I have, subject to these requirements?**

- It must be embeddable in a C++ application.
- It must work on Windows, Mac, Linux, and Android.
- It doesn't need to be a mainstream language like Python, but it must be teachable to someone entirely new to programming.

  - Haskell, Scheme, Prolog, etc. are right out unless you can convince me that they would be good first languages for an 11-year-old to learn.
- I need to be able to stop a script's execution at any time.

  - I can't kill the thread itself, so why not kill the scripting engine?
- I should have full control over the scripting context (e.g. what objects/functions/types are available).
- Qt integration would be nice, but is optional (I can make my own wrapper).
- It doesn't need to be very fast -- the player's code will run repeatedly, but no more than once every half-second or so.
- I must be able to call C++ functions from this scripting engine, and I must be able to call functions written in this scripting language from C++.

Comment: Actually, you might not need the ability to terminate the scripting engine at will. It might well be enough to be able to signal it that you want a long-running script terminated; or you could have it use time-outs internally, like [Javascript's setTImeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Also remember that you can instruct users to write simple scripts, using a small subset of the scripting language's grammar - and if they try writing something more complex, it's up to them. And a final note - check out what existing FOSS games use (0 A.D., Battle for Wesnoth, Cave Story) - at leasy some of them use a scripting engine, and you can get inspiration regarding _how_ to use it as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [Lua](https://www.lua.org).

- It is embeddable in C or C++
- It is portable (works on all platforms that have a C compiler)
- It is a rather easy language
- You can call into Lua from C++ and the other way round (even nested multiple times)
- You have full control over which functionality/objects/... are provided to the scripts
- From my understanding it should be feasible to terminate an executing Lua engine in a multithreaded environment

If you want to stay entirely inside C++, you might be interested in [luabind](https://github.com/luabind/luabind).

Comment: @JesseTG: [The Battle for Wesnoth](http://www.wesnoth.org/) uses Lua extensively.

Comment: Many games do: e.g. WoW (for user addons) and Civilization V, just to name 2 AAA titles from the top of my head

Comment: If Lua runs under a C++ thread, and you terminate it, you terminate the C++ thread and violate the OP's original objection.  Why is this an answer?